# Cocoa: take screenshot of desktop wallpaper (without icons and windows)

Tags: cocoa, screenshot, sandbox

Is is possible to capture the Mac OS X desktop without desktop items and any windows that may be open (i.e. just the wallpaper)?

I've experimented with `CGWindowListCreateImage`, `CGWindowListCreateImageFromArray`, and `CGDisplayCreateImage`, but no luck.

Essentially I'm trying to capture the desktop wallpaper without using `[NSWorkspace desktopImageURLForScreen:]` (it's a sandboxed app without access to the file system).

Comment: Wouldn't that just be your background picture?

Comment: @Heisenburg yes exactly. That's what I'm trying to capture (it's a sandboxed app so I can't read it from disk)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll need to be careful to test that this is still correct, but the desktop window sits below the Finder (it's drawn by the Dock). Passing the `kCGWindowListOptionOnScreenBelowWindow` `CGWindowListOption` to `CGWindowListCreateImage` should get you what you want (unless something else is drawing below that level).

Otherwise, you'll need to use `CGWindowListCreate` and iterate through the response excluding anything that isn't drawn by the dock at the window level `kCGMinimumWindowLevel + 19`.

It gets kind of tricky when there are multiple screens, but hopefully this information is enough for you to do what you need.

Answer (score 4):

I know this is a super old question, and Tony Arnold's question is right, and what I used to build my own "grab the desktop" code.

I have some example code that shows how to do all these things (it's a wonderful thing walking in parts of Cocoa that are barely documented... )

I've put that sample code up in a bitbucket repository. Specifically [the code sample to take a picture](https://bitbucket.org/rwilcox/learning_cocoa/src/tip/GettingDesktopPicture_InSandboxApp/image/AppDelegate.m#cl-28). (There's more interesting Cocoa code in my [learning Cocoa](https://bitbucket.org/rwilcox/learning_cocoa/) repository, where that sample code is from )

Answer (score 1):

Swift version:

```
extension NSImage {

    static func desktopPicture() -> NSImage {

        let windows = CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo(
            CGWindowListOption.OptionOnScreenOnly,
            CGWindowID(0))! as NSArray

        var index = 0
        for var i = 0; i < windows.count; i++  {
            let window = windows[i]

            // we need windows owned by Dock
            let owner = window["kCGWindowOwnerName"] as! String
            if owner != "Dock" {
                continue
            }

            // we need windows named like "Desktop Picture %"
            let name = window["kCGWindowName"] as! String
            if !name.hasPrefix("Desktop Picture") {
                continue
            }

            // wee need the one which belongs to the current screen
            let bounds = window["kCGWindowBounds"] as! NSDictionary
            let x = bounds["X"] as! CGFloat
            if x == NSScreen.mainScreen()!.frame.origin.x {
                index = window["kCGWindowNumber"] as! Int
                break
            }
        }

        let cgImage = CGWindowListCreateImage(
            CGRectZero,
            CGWindowListOption(arrayLiteral: CGWindowListOption.OptionIncludingWindow),
            CGWindowID(index),
            CGWindowImageOption.Default)!

        let image = NSImage(CGImage: cgImage, size: NSScreen.mainScreen()!.frame.size)
        return image
    }
}
```

Comment: NSZeroSize is shorthand for "same size as the CGImage".